# Using C++ objects within FreeRTOS Tasks

Tags: c, c++, compiler, freertos

I'd like to make use of object-oriented practises inside a FreeRTOS application. Is this as simple renaming files with task functions as .CPP, and instantiating objects, etc. inside the function, compiling as you normally would? Or, is some configuration involved?

Perhaps somebody could demonstrate with a sample "blinky" example, where the task itself is a C function, in which an object of some sort is created and used.

Comment: Wrong site. But the answer to the first paragraph would be - highly unlikely.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I presume you mean the first question?

Comment: Yeah. apparently it has two parts...

Comment: Take a look https://interactive.freertos.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/210028906-Using-FreeRTOS-with-C-

Answer (score 2):

There is no configuration required to use FreeRTOS tasks within a C++ application.

In the below example, a task is created inside a member function and the `this` object is passed to the task as a parameter. This way, the task can call public member functions of the object.

This example does not show it, but you can create C++ objects within the task function too.

```
void processingTask(void* pvParameters);

// init member function of MyClass class.
void MyClass::init()
{
    TaskHandle_t taskHandle = nullptr;
    // Create a task and pass `this` pointer to it.
    xTaskCreate(processingTask, "proc", 256, this, 5, &taskHandle);
}

// Static function - Task
void processingTask(void* pvParameters)
{
    // Cast the parameter to the pointer to the class.
    MyClass* obj = static_cast<MyClass*>(pvParameters);

    while (1) {
        // Call member function on the object.
        obj->doSomething();
        vTaskDelay(100);
    }
}
```

One place where you need to be careful, if you're defining functions that are called by FreeRTOS by name, like `vApplicationTickHook`. In that case, declare is as `extern "C"`, like so:

```
extern "C" void vApplicationTickHook(void)
{
    TickCount++;
}
```